# Finding the Equation of Circle, Given is its Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying for some quizzes when I stumbled upon  this question.
It goes like this:

> Find the equation of the circle whose differential equation is 
>   $y'' = (1 + (y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and which passes through the points 
>   (0, 0) and (1,1).

My work:

The differential equation $y'' = (1 + (y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ doesn't have a dependent 
variable $y,$ so we let

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = p$$
$$\frac{d^2 y}{ dx^2} = \frac{dp}{dx}$$

Now we had all we need, we can now solve for the general solution of 
$y'' = (1 + (y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$$y'' = (1 + (y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$ \left(\frac{dp}{dx}\right) = (1 + p^2)^\frac{3}{2}$$
$$dp = (1 + p^2)^\frac{3}{2} dx$$
$$\frac{dp}{(1 + p^2)^\frac{3}{2}} = dx$$
$$\int \frac{dp}{(1 + p^2)^\frac{3}{2}} = \int dx$$

Remembering that $\int \frac{du}{(u^2 + a^2)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{u}{a^2 \sqrt{u^2 + a^2}} + c$
$$\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2 + 1}} = x + c$$

$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2 + 1}} = x + c$$

$$\int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2 + 1}} = \int x + c$$

At this point, I'm stuck, because is it possible to do this?

$$\int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2 + 1}} = \int x + c$$

How will I go forward, and ultimately, getting the equation of the circle?

Comment: (Hint) The numerator looks like the derivative of whats inside the radical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2 + 1}} = x + c$$
$$\frac{y'^2}{(y')^2 + 1} = (x + c)^2 \quad\to\quad
y'^2 = \frac{(x + c)^2}{(1-(x + c)^2)}$$
$$y' =\pm \frac{x + c}{\sqrt{1-(x + c)^2}}$$
$$y =\pm \int\frac{x + c}{\sqrt{1-(x + c)^2}}dx=\mp\sqrt{1-(x + c)^2}+C$$
$$(y-C)^2+(x+c)^2=1$$
I suppose that you can take it from here to find the values of $C$ and $c$ according to the specified conditions.

Comment: I was able to move forward, but one thing scratches my head. how did you get the integral of $\pm \frac{x + c}{\sqrt{1-(x + c)^2}}.$ I was looking at my Table of Integrals, but to no avail. Maybe I will add this to my Table of Integrals?

Comment: This is not a new integral. Just change of variable : $$X=1-(x+c)^2\quad\to\quad dX=-2(x+c)dx \quad\to\quad y=\mp\int \frac{dX}{2\sqrt{X}}$$which is in your table.